# Pass data via ajax to laravel including array in answer

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a webpage that is sending data via ajax with data including text and also some variables that are arrays. My code is looking like this:

```
var data = {
        'action':action,
        'main_phase':main_phase,
        'secondary_phase':secondary_phase,
        'domain':domain,
        'description':description,
        'option':option,
        'assumption':assumption,
        'site':site_data,
        'quantity':quantity,
        'loe_per_quantity':loe_per_quantity,
        'formula':formula,
        'recurrent':recurrent,
        'start_date':start_date,
        'end_date':end_date,
        'cons':cons_data
      }
```

where site_data and cons_data that are arrays like this:

```
cons_data
0: [name: "business consultant", percentage: "0", price: "0"]
1: [name: "junior consultant", percentage: "50", price: "1000"]
2: [name: "lead consultant", percentage: "50", price: "1200"]
```

which is created like this:

```
      var cons_data = [];
      loe_data.col.cons.forEach(fill_cons_data_accept);
      function fill_cons_data_accept (cons,index){
        cons_data[index] = [];
        cons_data[index].name = cons.name;
        cons_data[index].percentage = $('input.loe_cons_percentage[data-name="'+cons.name+'"]').val();
        cons_data[index].price = $('input.loe_cons_price[data-name="'+cons.name+'"]').val();
      }
```

I m trying to send all this data to another page via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{!! route('loeCreateUpdate','') !!}/"+id,
            data:data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
            ...
```

And when I check what I receive on the other side with:

```
public function create_update(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $inputs = $request->all();

        return json_encode($inputs);
    }
```

I get everything except the 2 arrays.

Here is what I find through console.log():

1. what I send:

```
{
   action: "update"
   assumption: "The customer needs to come on site"
   cons: (3) [Array(0), Array(0), Array(0)]
   description: "Evaluate what the customer needs"
   domain: "Security"
   end_date: ""
   formula: "{{#site}}+{{ape}}-2*{{#site}}"
   loe_per_quantity: "5"
   main_phase: "BUILD"
   option: "option 1"
   quantity: "2"
   recurrent: 0
   secondary_phase: "workshop"
   site: [ape: Array(0), switches: Array(0), #site: Array(0)]
   start_date: ""
}
```

2. what I get back:

```
{
    action: "update"
    assumption: "The customer needs to come on site"
    description: "Evaluate what the customer needs"
    domain: "Security"
    end_date: null
    formula: "{{#site}}+{{ape}}-2*{{#site}}"
    loe_per_quantity: "5"
    main_phase: "BUILD"
    option: "option 1"
    quantity: "2"
    recurrent: "0"
    secondary_phase: "workshop"
    start_date: null
}
```

As you can see in the got back results, site and cons disappeared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the arrays to json string before appending it to the `data`

```
const site = JSON.stringify(site_data);
const cons = JSON.stringify(cons_data);

data.site = site;
data.cons = cons;
```

Or you can use jQuery's serializeArray

```
const site = $(site_data).serializeArray();
const cons = $(cons_data).serializeArray();

data.site = site;
data.cons = cons;
```

Verify the jQuery syntax - not too sure about it

Comment: I have tested what you gave me and indeed now I get the data on both sides but the problem is when I use stringify, I lose all data in the array and cons = [ [] [] [] ] without data inside the []. I will modify the text to show what I have.

Comment: To get the value of json stringified data you can try `$request->input('site')` or `json_decode($request->site, true)` to get the array in php

Comment: ok, I found my mistake, for the second part I should initiate with {} and not []